# Get category URL by category ID in WooCommerce on product details page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am looking for category URL on the product detail page. I am using below code to get category ID but I am not sure how to get category URL.

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

If you have the product category `id` you can use

```
$link = get_term_link( $product_cat_id, 'product_cat' );
```

To get the url of the product category.

**edit** be sure that the product_cat_id is an integer, use the following line to be completely save:

```
$link = get_term_link( (int)$product_cat_id, 'product_cat' );
```

Comment: if i can put that line in foreach its showing nothing.

Comment: @JustinK My bad, I forgot the second parameter, `get_term_link($term, $taxonomy)`

Comment: its working, but if that product have two categories its shwoing both because of foreach. can i get just first one ?

Comment: Sure instead of `foreach` just use `$terms[0]`. When it works you can mark or upvote the answer to show other users it helped.

Answer (score 3):

If a product belongs to one or many category then you can directly access the `$terms[0]` location and retrieve the URL

Here is the code:

```
global $post;
$link = '';
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
if(!empty($terms[0])){
    $link = get_term_link( $terms[0]->term_id, 'product_cat' );
}
```

Now just check `$link` is empty or not and do your required stuff.

*Code is tested and works.*

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `get_category_link(int|object $category)`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link/

And here how I use it on '`content-product_cat.php`'

```
<a href="<?php esc_url_e( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ); ?>">
        <h5 class="product-name"><?php esc_attr_e( $category->name ); ?></h5>
        <span class="dima-divider line-center line-hr small-line"></span>
        <span class="count">
        <?php  if ( $category->count > 0 ) {
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', $category->count . ' ' . ( $category->count > 1 ? __( 'Products', 'woocommerce' ) : __( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ) ), $category );
        }?>
        </span>
</a>
```